# How do you scrape ajax push sites

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, screen-scraping

Take a look at any live auction on http://www.quibids.com/ I wanted to scrape Bid History which appears to be being updated by a javascript timer.  When I inspect element in Chrome it auto-updates the source.  Is there some way to do that with screen scraping?  I'm using Ruby to do this if it matters.  What I want to avoid is just hammering on that page every second.

Comment: Inspect the AJAX requests that your browser is making, and mimic them.

Comment: If your intention to scrape this site is to "gain" an advantage over other bidders/bots I would be very careful.  This site looks like a clone (/sister) of Swoopo.  Such sites are a **barely legal** *scam* and as such I would avoid wasting your money on bidding: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/profitable-until-deemed-illegal.html

Comment: @dimitrov - sorry - i actually didn't know i had to go accept answers.  i went back and accepted ones.

Comment: @scunliffe - just collecting stats for someone whose doing a project.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073481/headless-scriptable-firefox-webkit-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

You could use a browser engine that can execute the javascript, such as webkit (there's a scriptable wrapper for it, [WebkitDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webkitdriver/)).

Or check what the javascript timer is doing via a tool like firebug. Likely it is making an AJAX request to get the updated data and you can call these AJAX URL's directly.

Comment: There's a fully scriptable headless browser named HTMLUnit, but it's in Java.

Comment: webkit is also scriptable and can run headless

Comment: Not sure if we're using the same definition of "scriptable" - I'm not aware of a webkit-based browser that can be *fully programatically controlled by another program, without user intervention*; but then, I'm not claiming to know everything ;) Could you share a link to such project?

Comment: You piqued my curiosity, and it turns out that you were right: [one of the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073481/headless-scriptable-firefox-webkit-on-linux) mentions [WebkitDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webkitdriver/). Could you edit that into the answer? I don't think it would warrant its own answer, but would fit into yours well.

Comment: feel free to update my answer if you think it is a good solution for asker.