# Simulate chrome/firefox browser (for javascript testing)

Tags: javascript

Using command line in linux, how can i call a webpage and get its content simulating a chrome or firefox browser. I also need for the browser to be javascript capable so it outputs the exact final html.

Thanks.

Comment: This question might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073481/headless-scriptable-firefox-webkit-on-linux

Comment: To get a Webpage via Commandline you can use `curl` and set the UAS accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search i will be using phantomjs, http://phantomjs.org/